# Chromosomes: Vulcan vs Spock vs humans

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, genetics

How many chromosomes does a Vulcan have? How many does Spock have? Would one have alleles that would automatically outweigh all of the others?

Is it possible for a half human half Vulcan to have rounded ears? Or is it only possible for such a match to produce pointed ear offspring?

Comment: The second part seems like a separate question from the first. Whether Vulcan/human children can have rounded ears is not really related to the number of chromosomes, though they are both about genetics. Perhaps you could ask the second part separately?